# When and how many times does Meteor retry to connect to a failed DDP connection?

Tags: meteor, ddp

Suppose I have a DDP connection to a worker:

```
var worker = DDP.connect(workerUrl);
```

If the connection to that worker suddenly fails in the future, how many times does Meteor retry to resolve the connection? And when does it do that?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question but [meteor-cluster](https://github.com/meteorhacks/cluster) helps to deal with this kind of problems.

Comment: @MikeC it's the same as for a client disconnect from your meteor app. I found it to be retries to infinity x 2 time last time  (e.g. retry to reconnect in 10, 20, 40, 80, 160 and so on) to get the exact logic you will have to dig the source in meteor. Maybe this is helpful ;)